# Access Nested Data from JSONField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class BaseTransaction(models.Model):
    """Model to store JSON data"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    json_data = JSONField(null=True)
```

If I create an instance with the following data:

```
 base_transaction = models.BaseTransaction.objects.create(
            name="Test Transaction",
            json_data={{"sales": 3.24, "date": "2020-06-05"},
                       {"sales": 5.50, "date": "2020-06-04"},
                       {"sales": 256.53, "date": "2020-06-02"}}
        )
```

How would I access the second row of data without a key? Or is this the wrong format for JSON? I am using this format because the original data is from a CSV and this is how it converts to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the above structure is not in`JSON` format. You can always validate if it's `JSON` or not using [JSON Formatter  & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

You would want to restructure is according to the rules of `JSON`, and manually if that can be done so. Once it's in `JSON` format, you can access the second row without `keys` using a for loop and a counter, e.g.

```
counter = 0    
for (key in obj) {
    counter+=1
    if (counter == 2): 
        # Do anything 
    else:
       print("Key: " + key)
       print("Value: " + obj[key])
}
```